# Apply directory permissions to all new subdirectories in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, chmod, subdirectory

I have a shared folder that is used in our LAN development environment that needs to always have rwx permissions for everyone.  When Jenkins builds our application however it copies over files to be available and doesn't give guests the ability to write to the files.

So under this directory for any new sub directory or file in a sub directory it basically has to do a chmod 777 to it.

I tried `sudo setfacl -Rm g:users:rwX,d:g:users:rwX index/`

which gave the parent directory the permissions of drwxrwxrwx+, and all of the sub directories and files have the + but they kept their original permissions.

How do I always make everything in this folder 777?

Comment: You may want to use `umask`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/44534/how-to-set-umask-for-a-specific-folder for further references

Comment: I just tried setting the umask to 0000, when I do `umask -S` it shows `u=rwx g=rwx o=rwx` but when I do a `ls -l` it doesn't seem to have changed the permissions of its contents

Comment: The umask works for the creation of *future* files/dirs. It does not work retrospectively.

Comment: Oh, awesome, just created a file with `umask 0000` set and it has read and write for all the files I just tried creating, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most unix command come with a recursive option. In this case:

```
-R, --recursive
```

It seems like you are trying to use this, but you have `-Rm`.  That is not the correct option.

I think what you need is:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m g:users:rwX,d:g:users:rwX index/
```

I typically use `chmod` instead of `setfacl`.

```
chmod -R 777 *
```

Comment: hmm I tried `sudo setfacl -R -m g:users:rwX,d:g:users:rwX index/` and my test file that has the permissions of `-rw-rw-r--+` kept its permissions, along with the others.  Is there something that could be blocking it?

The files are also under ownership of the user I am logged in as.